# how to transform XML to XML client side

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

the Problem - Need to transform an XML file to a new XML file (filtering some rubbish off)

Current scenario - Our program creates an XML file when the client runs an HTML report from the software (have written HTML the files that use Javascript to load the XSL and XML transformation)

Currently the above scenario works for just creating HTML out, but I need now to output as XML, and every time I try and and view this HTML file in IE as that is what starts the process to generate the transformation, I just get the node answers, no XML tree.. what am I missing here?

**Sample HTML file that is loaded from software:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <link href="Common/CMStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script language="JavaScript" src="ReportHeader.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body onload="displayResult('sample.xsl');">
    <div id="report"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**ReportFunctions.js**

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
  if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
    xmldom = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmldom.async = false;
    xmldom.load(dname);
    return xmldom;
  }
  else
  {
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
  }
}

function displayResult(stylename)
{
  xml=loadXMLDoc("TempReportData/CabExportData.xml");
  xsl=loadXMLDoc(stylename);

  if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
    document.getElementById("report").innerHTML=xml.transformNode(xsl);
  }
  else
  {
    xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
    resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
    if (document.getElementById("report").hasChildNodes())
    {
      document.getElementById("report").removeChild(document.getElementById("report").lastChild);
    }
    document.getElementById("report").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
```

**Sample XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report schema="1.0">
   <Item name="cabinet" id="1" />
   <Item name="cabinet" id="2" />
   <Item name="cabinet" id="3" />
   <DocumentProperties>
      <PageProperties name="Page 1" pagenum="1" />
      <Paths>
         <Data>C:\Data\</Data>
         <Library>C:\Library\</Library>
         <Table>C:\Table\</Table>
         <Picture>C:\Bitmap\</Picture>
         <Report>C:\Report\</Report>
         <Template>C:\Template\</Template>
         <Backup>C:\Backup\</Backup>
         <Program>C:\</Program>
      </Paths>
      <Application>
         <Product>CabPro</Product>
         <Family>Software</Family>
         <Version>8.0.61.2700</Version>
         <Build>2013.10.4.0</Build>
         <Desc />
         <Company>Q1</Company>
         <Account>QSystems Pty Ltd</Account>
      </Application>
   </DocumentProperties>
</Report>
```

**Sample XSL file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|DocumentProperties/Paths"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expectation: from all of the above I expect to see in an HTML browser the XML tree filtering off the excess and showing me a tree of the remaining of Paths

Actual result... in IE looks a little like this..
C:\Data\ C:\Library\ C:\Table\C:\Bitmap\ C:\Report\ C:\Template\ C:\Backup\ C:\

*note with no Tree of XML?

am I missing something here? or has someone got some suggestions to try to get this to work, it has to be done client side.

Comment: I suppose there is another point to note here: don't mind not seeing the output XML as long as I can trigger a file with its information inside, and designate a download location for it with an *.xml

Comment: Ok i have been testing and playing with this all day.
It turns out all along I am getting the correct XML output, but the browser is not showing me the tags as it doesnt know how to process them. So what I need to do is ignore the fact I cannot see the output, as the outputs visual appearance is not important, what I do need is the ability to SAVE the output, So I need a way to give the user the ability to hit a button and save the Transformed XML to their computer.

Comment: You might like to look at Saxon-CE for writing such applications. However, Saxon-CE doesn't have an XML serializer (something that converts the XML from tree representation to angle-bracket representation), and in any case the ability to save a file from the browser to the filestore of the local machine is very dependent on browser security settings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Michael, but that also looks like a similar idea I was already considering which involved getting PHP available at the client side to handle the additional request, but its not very practical for what I am trying to do.. which is very unfortunate. We cannot really install more programs on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have an xslt editor here to check but have you tried this

```
<xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
```

instead of

```
<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
```

I would try that on both templates.